# How do I use the model as a datasource for Kendo UI grid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, model, telerik, kendo-grid

I am only getting a grid with no data inside. I am new to MVC and have not been able to find how to add data into the grid using just the model that is passed to the view page. Below is the code that I have used

Controller code:

```
  public ActionResult List()
    {
        List<CustomerModel> list = new List<CustomerModel>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            CustomerModel model = new CustomerModel();
            model.Id = 1;
            model.Name = "Alice";
            model.Address = "Blk "+i;
            model.PostalCode = ""+i+i+i;
            model.Email = i+"@yahoo.com";
            model.TelephoneNumber = i + i + i + i + i + i+"";
            list.Add(model);
        }


        return View(list);
    }
    public ActionResult Read()
    {
        List<CustomerModel> list = new List<CustomerModel>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            CustomerModel model = new CustomerModel();
            model.Id = 1;
            model.Name = "Alice";
            model.Address = "Blk " + i;
            model.PostalCode = "" + i + i + i;
            model.Email = i + "@yahoo.com";
            model.TelephoneNumber = i + i + i + i + i + i + "";
            list.Add(model);
        }


        return View(list);
    }
```

View Code:

```
@using TKMVC.Models
@model IEnumerable<CustomerModel>


@(Html.Kendo().Grid<CustomerModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .ServerOperation(true)
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(p => p.Id);
            model.Field(p => p.Id).Editable(false);
        })
        .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Home"))
    )
)
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing local and ajax data binding and you haven't defined any columns in the grid.

Try passing the model into the grid, define grid columns and remove the read request from your data source. Most probably you need to turn off server operations in your case.

Your grid statement should then look like this:

```cs
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<CustomerModel>(Model)
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(m => m.Id);
        columns.Bound(m => m.Name);
    })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .ServerOperation(false)
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(p => p.Id);
            model.Field(p => p.Id).Editable(false);
        })
    )
)
```

Comment: I am getting " Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type" at the line where ".DataSource(dataSource => dataSource" What does this mean?

Comment: No idea. This should work. The only string in this statement is the grid name.

Comment: The only difference to the example from Telerik is the model definition. If that really is the problem, it could be a bug and worth reporting to Telerik.